# Node JS cli script crashing when packaged to a executable with pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, exe, executable

A very simple script for web automation for filling out a form using puppeteer, works perfectly in my IDE when I run it with **node filename.js**

But when I package it into a executable with `pkg`, it crashes on the first instance of input without any error being thrown, I don't expect a direct solution to this issue but maybe someone had a similar experience and can tell me what might be causing this, as I have no idea what to do right now.

The code:

```
    const puppeteer = require('./node_modules/puppeteer')

const parse = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const data = [];

menu()

async function menu() {
    console.log("Please select a option\n\n" +
    "1. The Streets raffle\n" +
    "2. Footshop raffle\n" +
    "3. Exit");
    rl.question("", async function(answer) {
        console.log(`user choice: ${answer}`);

        if(answer === "1") {
            console.log("streets module starting");
            await streets_module();
        }
        else if(answer === "2") {
            console.log("In development, press enter to exit");
            rl.question("", async function(answer) {
            });
            rl.close;
            process.exit(0);
        }
        else if(answer === "3"){
            console.log("Now exitting...");
            rl.close;
            process.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            console.log("undefined choice, exitting...");
            rl.close;
            process.exit(0);
        }
        
    });
}

async function streets_module() {
    fs.createReadStream("profiles.csv") // this part can be omitted and instead the array from below can be assigned to the data variable
    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',' }))
    .on('data', (r) => {
        //console.log("r: ", r);
        data.push(r);        
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
        //console.log("data: ",data);
        //console.log("data at 1: ", data[1][0]); // prvy profil

        console.log("data length: ", data.length, data);

        for (let ii = 1; ii < data.length; ii++) {
            //console.log("this triggered");
            //C:\chrome-win\chrome.exe
            //console.log("async block triggered");
            console.log(`profile ${ii} started`)
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']});
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto('https://www.thestreets.sk/online-raffle/');
            await page.type("#name", data[ii][0]); // ,{ delay: 100 });
            await page.type("#yourEmail", data[ii][1]);//, { delay: 100 });
            await page.type("#phone", data[ii][2]);//, { delay: 100 });
            await page.type("#street", data[ii][3]);//, { delay: 100 });
            await page.type("#city", data[ii][4]);//, { delay: 100 });
            await page.type("#psc", data[ii][5]);//, { delay: 100 });
            await page.select('select#state', data[ii][6]);//, { delay: 100 }); 
            await page.select('select#prefered_size_sel', data[ii][7]);//, { delay: 100 });
            await page.$eval('input[name="agreed_personal_info_tiny_contact_form"]', check => check.checked = true);
        
        
            await page.screenshot({ path: 'streets' + ii + '.png' });
        
            await page.click('input[name="submit"]');
            
            //console.log("async block finished");
            console.log(`profile ${ii} finished`);
            await browser.close();
        }
        console.log("all profiles traversed, closing...");
        process.exit(0);
    })
    
}
```

The csv file holds some testing data to see if the form gets filled out correctly, here's the data in a array for testing purposes:

```
    [
  [
    'Full name',
    'Email',
    'Phone number',
    'Street',
    'City',
    'Postal code',
    'State',
    'Size'
  ],
  [
    'test',
    'test@test.com',
    '090123456789',
    'ulica',
    'Presov',
    '10902',
    'SVK',
    '5W'
  ],
  [
    'test 2',
    'test2@test.com',
    '090123452789',
    'ulica2',
    'Presov2',
    '10903',
    'SVK',
    '6W'
  ]
]
```

A video of the issue:
[a video showcase of the issue](https://youtu.be/Jl2ogT7f-aY)

Thank you for getting this far and for any possible suggestions as to why the exe file is crashing :)

Comment: Is this all your code? Because if it is, you program isn't crashing but just exiting because you don't call any of the functions you defined. You jsut define a bunch of `const`s and `async function`s but don't do anything with them. Which makes me wonder how that would work if you call it via `node filename.js`

Comment: no haha :D there is the rl readline library which acts as a input gatherer from user, so  `rl.question("", async function(answer)`  will wait until the user inputs their choice, if it is choice 1 and I start the script in my IDE it loops through the profiles and makes screenshots of them being filled out. But in the executable it instantly closes without making any screenshots, also I receive no email confirmations of filling the form with the .exe compared to running the script in my IDE

Comment: I will edit the question with a video embed so that it makes more sense

Comment: Well, yes `rl` in principle will gather the input. But without ever calling `menu()` how will the menu be displayed and when will `rl.question( ...)` be called? The answer is *never*  thus the program exists ...

Comment: @derpirscher yes I deleted a part of the code where I call menu my bad, because there was a ascii art logo which was pointless for this problem, still the problem is elsewhere, I just forgot to add `menu()` into the snippet

Comment: run the exe from PS so you can see what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the csv file name with its absolute path instead, in case the directory from which it is being accessed isn't the same

Comment: thanks, such a stupid mistake, but it worked. comment from @pguardiario also made it easier to debug the exe file, thanks to everyone